# Which feature of kotlin can be used as a replacedment of method interception via java proxies

Tags: java, kotlin, interceptor, dynamic-proxy, delegated-properties

In java if I want to **intercept the method calls** on a class I can use `Proxy.newProxyInstance()` and provide an `InvocationHandler` implementing `invoke()`.

I've seen that in kotlin you can use **delegated properties** to kind of intercept property access.

Is there any feature of kotlin that could be used to provide similar functionality for methods?

Comment: which features are you looking for? I mean, you can always build something around the current proxy implementation that would look more kotlin-ish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kotlin does not have a standard and unified way to create `Proxies`. You can still use `Proxy.newProxyInstance()` when using the K/JVM platform, but keep in mind the Kotlin compiler will generate/rename method (you can use `@JvmName` to kind of control that). On the JS platform there is a somewhat similar feature ([MDN doc here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)), and you have `@JsName` to handle method renaming.

As for Native there is (to my knowledge) no way of doing it as reflection is not implemented.

The goal of delegation is not to provide an alternatives to proxy, but you might get away with them for some use cases.

There is a feature request for this feature [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-34399), but it did not received much attention